# Windows 11にてDocker ComposeでRuby 3.2.2とRails、MySQL 8.xでwebとdbサービスをbuildできるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker-compose

[※こちらでも同様の質問をしています。](https://teratail.com/questions/fygq1fxrrj5s26)

Windows 11上にDocker Desktop 4.25.2をインストールしています。
エディタはVSCodeで、ターミナルから各種コマンドを実行しています。

### うまくいったこと

`docker compose run web rails new . --force --database=mysql`
はエラー無く実行完了できた。

### うまくいっていないこと

「うまくいったこと」の完了後、`docker compose build` を実行すると以下の様に途中で強制的に停止してしまう。

```
> docker compose --verbose build --no-cache
time="2023-12-17T20:33:09+09:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\haya-\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
[+] Building 1.9s (6/9)                                                             docker:default
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 515B                                                          0.0s
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.2                               1.5s
 => CACHED [web 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.2@sha256:e3f503db7f451e6fd48221ecafbf1046  0.0s
 => CANCELED [web internal] load build context                                                0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.40MB                                                           0.1s
 => CANCELED [web 2/5] RUN curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearm  0.3s
time="2023-12-17T20:33:09+09:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\haya-\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
time="2023-12-17T20:33:09+09:00" level=debug msg="serving grpc connection"
time="2023-12-17T20:33:09+09:00" level=debug msg="stopping session" span="load buildkit capabilities"
time="2023-12-17T20:33:10+09:00" level=debug msg="serving grpc connection"
time="2023-12-17T20:33:11+09:00" level=debug msg="stopping session"
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

### ソースコードとフォルダ構成

フォルダ構成は以下

```
App
├src
│└Gemfile
├compose.yml
└Dockerfile
- Gemfile
```

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo_name|"https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }
gem "rails"
```

- compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password
    volumes:
      - ./src/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2

RUN curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt update && apt install -y yarn nodejs

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src /app

RUN bundle config --local set path 'vendor/bundle' \
    && bundle install
```

### 試したこと

1. 動作しているコンテナの確認

```
> docker compose ps
NAME                 IMAGE          COMMAND                   SERVICE   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
rails_docker2-db-1   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db        11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

2. web用のコンテナを一時的に立ち上げてDockerfileの各コマンドを実行してみた。

```
> docker compose run --rm web /bin/bash  
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                             docker:default
[+] Creating 1/0
 ✔ Container rails_docker2-db-1  Created                                                      0.0s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container rails_docker2-db-1  Started                                                      0.3s 
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                             docker:default
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg
File '/etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# echo "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
15 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# apt install -y yarn nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
yarn is already the newest version (1.22.19-1).
nodejs is already the newest version (18.13.0+dfsg1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# bundle config --local set path 'vendor/bundle'
root@b74cd8667f8a:/app# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake 13.1.0
（略）
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 82 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rubyzip:
RubyZip 3.0 is coming!
```

### 解決策がわからず、調査を自分で続ける場合に知りたいこと

- 以下で止まっていそうで、yarnpubkey.gpgをrun時に作成したためにbuild時にファイルが存在するので停止しているような気がしますが、何を試せばよいか知りたいです。

```
gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/yarnpubkey.gpg
```

### 補足情報

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
（略）
    public_suffix (5.0.4)
    puma (6.4.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rack (3.0.8)
    rack-session (2.0.0)
      rack (>= 3.0.0)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rackup (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 3)
      webrick (~> 1.8)
    rails (7.1.2)
      actioncable (= 7.1.2)
      actionmailbox (= 7.1.2)
      actionmailer (= 7.1.2)
      actionpack (= 7.1.2)
      actiontext (= 7.1.2)
      actionview (= 7.1.2)
      activejob (= 7.1.2)
      activemodel (= 7.1.2)
      activerecord (= 7.1.2)
      activestorage (= 7.1.2)
      activesupport (= 7.1.2)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.1.2)
    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    railties (7.1.2)
      actionpack (= 7.1.2)
      activesupport (= 7.1.2)
      irb
      rackup (>= 1.0.0)
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.2)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.6)
    rake (13.1.0)
    rdoc (6.6.2)
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
    regexp_parser (2.8.3)
    reline (0.4.1)
      io-console (~> 0.5)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (4.16.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sprockets (4.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stimulus-rails (1.3.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    stringio (3.1.0)
    thor (1.3.0)
    timeout (0.4.1)
    turbo-rails (1.5.0)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.2.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)
    websocket (1.2.10)
    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.12)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  capybara
  debug
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  mysql2 (~> 0.5)
  puma (>= 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.1.2)
  selenium-webdriver
  sprockets-rails
  stimulus-rails
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.2.2p53

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.10
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/fygq1fxrrj5s26) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 失礼しました。ありがとうございます。両方にその旨明示しておきます。勉強になりました。